# ASP.NET MVC Entity admin CRUD

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, crud

Im looking for something similar to rails admin for asp.net.

Essentially I need to write an admin layer that allows most table data to be changed / searched etc.

I could generate basic scaffolding however I'm wondering if there is a free or commercial admin package that would give a nice UI admin interface to the data.

Ideally I need to be able to control and add logic to it also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I create [Ilaro.Admin](https://github.com/rgonek/Ilaro.Admin) and it is exactly what you looking for, but please keep in mind there are a lot of stuff to do.